# Why do Sabarimala devotees wear Black clothes ?

Tags: belief, culture, customs

Black cloth is usual considered inauspicious and not used especially when visiting a temple. But devotee of Ayyappa  wears black clothes when they visit Sabarimala. Is there any reason for this practice. Does this have any related to Shanni ?

Comment: There is a same question on yahoo  on the topic..was it u who asked it?because there too Shani is spelled as **Shanni** like u did in the question..

Comment: According to [official website](http://sabarimala.kerala.gov.in/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=92&Itemid=94): "Devotee is expected wear black/blue/saffron clothes."

Answer (score 7):

Since *AyyappA* is not a *puranic* *deva*, the fables and legends around him are not found in *purana* and *upanishads*, rather exclusively in *kshetra-puranas* or local temple histories.

AyyappA is said to have a conversation with Shani about him (Shani) causing trouble to people, on which Shani replied that it's his *dharma* to do so. On this, AyyappA asked for Shani to leave his devotees out of his misery for which he laid out certain rules,

- It is believed that one would get relief from *Shani* *dosha* by taking the *Ayyappa* *Deeksha*. This is because Lord *AyyappA* commanded Shani not to trouble his devotees.
- Shani affects a person for seven years, but Lord *AyyappA* said to Shani that his devotees would take the *deeksha* for 41 days and experience the same difficulties that Shani would have given in a span of seven years by not caring for their appearances (not grooming facial hair etc), eating only once a day, bathing in cold water (generally in *sharada RRitu*) and sleeping on a floor and practicing *brahmAcharya*.
- In return, *AyyappA* assured Shani that his **devotees would wear black/blue dress** which is the colour associated with *Shani*.

This is the reason why lord Ayyappa devotees wear black dress.

Further reading

- [Hindupad](https://hindupad.com/lord-ayyappa-and-shani/)

Comment: But according to [official website](http://sabarimala.kerala.gov.in/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=92&Itemid=94): "Devotee is expected wear black/blue/saffron clothes."

Comment: @ Vinnet Menon Can you provide the source. I understand that there is not reference to Ayyappa in Puranas.